# What is the role of $\mathcal{f(-x)=f(x)}, \ \forall \mathcal{x}$ in a binomial distribution?

Tags: probability

The problem says :-

> Let $\mathrm{X_1, X_2, ... , X_n}$ be $\mathrm{n}$ iid random variables with pdf $\mathcal{f(x)}$ such that $\mathcal{f(-x)=f(x)}, \ \forall \mathcal{x}$. Let $\mathrm{Y}$ denote the number of positive signs among $\mathrm{X_1, X_2, ... , X_n}$. Find the distribution of $\mathrm{Y}$.

I understand that $\mathrm{Y}$ denotes the total number of success ( if we consider positive signs as success ) in $\mathrm{n}$ trials (considering each i.i.d. random variables as a single trial) hence Y follows a binomial distribution.

> I am having problem regarding describing the role of
> $\mathcal{f(-x)=f(x)}, \ \forall \mathcal{x}$  in this problem.

My guess goes in this manner:-  no matter how many positive or negative values the iid r.v $\mathrm{X_i}$'s take, the p.m.f  yields same value for both of the entries. And this gives an idea of symmetry and a binomial distribution is symmetric when its success probability i.e. $\mathcal{p}=\frac{1}{2}$.

My proof is incomplete as I am not sure if my interpretation of $\mathcal{f(-x)=f(x)}, \ \forall \mathcal{x}$ is correct. Any help regarding this specific part is valuable and appreciated.

Comment: Is $n$ odd? ${}$

Comment: If the PDF is even then it imposes on the CDF that less than 0 is the same as greater than 0, so each sign has equal chance of happening.

Comment: no information about $n$ is provided in the problem. I guess it is even.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis one hint given with the question suggests to use $\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{X_i}<0)=q=\sum_{-\infty}^{0}\mathcal{f(x)}$. I did not understand at first whethere it is relevant in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume continuous random variables because you called $f$ a p.d.f, but will tell you how to do the discrete case after the intuition is established. By definition, we have:

$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy$$

If $f(y) = f(-y)$ then $$P(X > 0) = 1-F(0) = \int_0^\infty f(y)dy$$

By change of variables, and using evenness of $f$

$$ =-\int_0^{-\infty} f(-y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^0 f(y)dy = F(0)$$

So the probability of $X$ being negative, which is $F_X(0)$ by definition equals the probability of being positive, which is $1-F_X(0)$ and both are one half.

This proof is exactly the same in the discrete case, instead of change of variables we reindex the summation. However, there is a big caveat in the discrete case in which we must have $f(0)=0$, which holds automatically for a continuous random variable.

If you don't assume this then instead of the Bernoulli trial - or + we have a categorical random variable -,+,0 with probabilities:

$$\frac{1}{2}(1-f(0)), \frac{1}{2}(1-f(0)), f(0)$$

and the resulting distribution that counts outcomes ought to be multinominal, not binomial.

Comment: +1 . Wow, I did not even think in this detail and thank you for this amazing detailed answer.